# Is "eoddata" a good data source?

Tags: data, market-data

Not sure if this is a relevant question for site, but I am looking to move to  [www.eoddata.com](http://www.eoddata.com/) as my data source.

If anyone has used it, can you tell me how the data quality is ?

I am currently parsing yahoo for my prices but its not a very efficient process.

What are the other sources of equity data out there ( affordable for retail investors like me) ? I am willing to pay \$250-\$300 per year for it.

Comment: I believe the initial question is OK for the site, but I would straightaway remove the "what are the other data sources" from the question or it **will** be closed as this question already exists.

Comment: I think the question of data quality is hard to answer unless somebody had a trusted source to compare the data with.

Comment: Don't use EOD data!!! Their support is stupid and unqualified. Often I didn't get any response for my questions at all. And, what is more significant, their data is corrupted and contain prices that have never been in reality.

Comment: As an alternative consider eodhistoricaldata. Ive been using eodhistorical as training data, and then testing algos using live data via a paper trading account on alpaca. So far so good. Their customer service is great, pricing is fair ($50 a month), they will have 20years of intra day minute data available by the end of May 2020, and they are working on adding pre and after hours data at some point over the summer of 2020. So far, I have seen minimal errors using their 5min ticks data, retrospectively comparing their data to the live data I collect via alpaca.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From my experience, EODData is pretty much that you get what you pay for. Its not a very sophisticated product. They email you the files you subscribe to, and thats that. I have had an issue before of where the emails didn't go through anymore and I never heard anything from them.

On Quality,
I can't make a claim on its accuracy. It seems good. I find issue with three things about the data:

1. There is no way to signal an exchange change
2. It doesn't give you an easy way to grab the symbol info [Names, etc]
3. If there is a stock split or dividend, it does not mention this in the data.

That being said, it does do a good job with keeping a simple file format, and providing "long term" historical data.

Answer (score 24):

Don't use them.  I have used them for years because I couldn't find another source that would provide all stocks in all US exchanges -- till now.  But first, about eoddata:

1. their data is very often missing elements, e.g., on any given day the SP500 index data my not be in their data set, even for a normal trading day
2. their ftp files are often out of date, meaning if you need the previous day's data, you might have to wait a day or more to get it
3. their customer support is absolutely useless.  You can't phone them (there is no phone  number on their website), all you can do is fill out a web form.  Most times I never got a response, and when I did, it was perfunctory and absolutely no help
4. In order to cancel your "subscription", they need a written cancellation notice.  I sent them just such a notice via certified mail.  I have verified that they received it on April 20, 2012, and yet today, 4/24/2012, I just received notice that they are billing me again for the coming month.
5. I found a phone number for eoddata on bbb.com, but no one never answers, all there is is a message, after 20 rings or so, saying "try again later"

Bottom line: if you need your data to be there every day on schedule, DO NOT  use eoddata.

The good news: premiumdata.net is an excellent service in every way -- data quality, dependability, customer support.  They are more expensive than eoddata, but you get what you pay for.

Comment: I don't see two items I need at premiumdata.net: n-Minute bars and Canadian equities.  I did ask EODData.com about their cancellation policy, and they claimed I could cancel by e-mail any time.  I'm weighing either EODData (with a live feed from my broker or QuoteMedia) against IQFeed.

FWIW, there is a review of feeds at

  http://www.trade2win.com/reviews/data_feeds

Comment: I've had issues with help as well. [Watch out they can recover your plain text password]
Also, I haven't had an issue where cancelation is difficult... I've had the opposite ... its too easy and they're overly sensitive about billing

Answer (score 14):

Don't use them. Their data is very spotty. They offer "minute by minute" data on commodities markets and forex which should be technically 24hrs yet it usually starts from 9 or 11 o clock and the "minutes" end around 3 or 4. I emailed their support alias asking why this was the case. I also copied and pasted the opening and closing times of the exchanges and here is a response i got

> Sorry but the website you are referring to is not our website, the
>   times stated on the website you have mentioned do not reflect the data
>   we provide.
>
> Kind Regards, Nick Kruger | Customer Service EODData, LLC 444 N.
>   Michigan Ave, Suite 1200 Chicago, IL 60611 www.eoddata.com

Good luck also finding a phone number to reach them at.

Comment: Can you provide an alternative ?

Comment: IQfeed. for 65 bucks a month you get access to delayed NYSE, NASDAQ, AMEX. for an extra 5 dollars per exchange you have access to real time data.

Answer (score 10):

Don't use eoddata unless you absolutely have to.  I purchased long history of global index and forex prices.  There are hundreds and hundreds of incorrectly missing or completely wrong prices.  For example (big problem with forex), the price is coming along in the 10s, then spkes up to the 1000's for a few days before dropping back down.  Repeat over and over again.  The worst is when it's the opposite; should be 1s, but incorrectly recorded as .01s - not nough decimals to rescale. This is an obviously stupid error, especially since they claim

> *EODData runs a number of computers that scan the data 24x7 to find anomalies and correct the prices that are clearly wrong. We also compare our data against other sources to double check whether we have the right figures. As a final measure we have staff who spend all day finding and correcting data problems*.

How about FOREX tickers where suddenly there are no prices for several months?  This is also relatively common in their data.  One of them goes AWOL for 3 years.

Furthermore, repeated attempts to get them to fix the data, after I have already spent hours and hours identifying & fixing what I can are less than successful.

Most recent response from support:

> Sorry but we no long have the resources available to correct the errors you have mentioned.

Can we say false advertising?

Comment: Tried them and was not satisfied with the data quality.

Answer (score 8):

I am an Oracle Database Administrator.  I subscribe to EODdata for daily minute-tick price data.  When I upload their datasets into my database I run consistency checks before the data is finalized.  I can confirm the wildly swinging price spikes other users have identified, plus data gaps, plus the same stock listed on multiple exchanges, plus entire multiple-hour blocks of trading data simply missing - in other words, as a database professional, when you run a fine-toothed comb across their data using multiple orthogonal angles, you will find just about every category of "dirty data" in their datasets.  Why do I still use them?  I can run scripts on my database that identify and resolve obvious problems automatically, and for my backtesting purposes that suffices.  But for anybody who doesn't have Oracle database resources or raw machine power to resolve dirty data, I would recommend against EODdata.  And yes, OH YES, tech support is abysmal - effectively non-existent.  I have even offered my services to Nick Kruger to help him provide a higher quality data product, but no answer.  If you google "Nick Kruger EODdata" or "EODdata quality" you will always find the same user answers, and that is, "you get what you pay for."  I have been actively trying to find a higher quality data source (hard to beat $30 a month for EODdata) - I'd be willing to pay triple that cost for good data and decent tech support, but so far have not found it.

Answer (score 7):

I have used eoddata for an analysis of open interest with a history of 10 years daily data. Since it was the only source, i can't comment on the data quality. What I comment on is that the interesting data could be extracted efficiently from the source files (which will give you a csv per day for the data of an exchange).

Comment: Is the data availablatom a timely manner at 5 pm? I am planning to go with the platinum package.

Comment: I wasn't updating the data, just pulled the historical archives, so I have no idea about the update time.

Answer (score 7):

I saw a lot of "DON'T USE THEM" messages so I think the OP might benefit from a little more comprehensive answer that puts things in perspective. Firstly, understand that no data source is perfect. I have worked with reuters, csidata , eoddata, google, yahoo and they will always have some problems. It is understandable to some extent because:
a) often exchanges themselves do not report correct data or there was an amendment to the cross price, busted trades etc.
b) splits and dividends create errors (google's data is supposed to be split adjusted, but not for dividend. Yet there are numerous examples where it's not true)
c) some vendors ignore splits and divs given on non trading days- that creates problems
d) tickers change or get delisted and then in a few years some other company or class or shares is assigned that ticker.

Good news is generally I have noticed different vendors have different problem and by combining two or more data sources you can reduce errors exponentially. But be careful as different vendors use different notations to represent class/preferred shares.

Reuters is excellent in keeping track of name-changes/delistings. Their price, split/div is also most accurate. If you have money and want the best, go with them. CSI's split/div data is good, but they have atleast 5% error in prices. EODDATA has good op/tp but don't give historical split/divs and have no customer support. In order of quality I would rank the ones I know as:

1. REUTERS - expensive - errors less than 0.1%
2. CSIDATA - budget - errors 5% in prices, less than 0.1% in split/divs
3. EODDATA - budget - errors less than 0.1% in prices. no historical split/divs
4. GOOGLE  - free   - errors 2 to 4%
5. YAHOO   - free   - slightly worse than google, but deteriorating fast

Answer (score 5):

We are a new start-up (today actually) producing easy charting software for the lowest price we can. We are using EODData and we find it to be very good. There are no issues in the quality of the data for us, and it seems to update very timely for the charting purposes and our own investing purposes. Our software is distributed free, so if you want to check out the quality of their data without paying a cent, give it a go. The free version gives you 1 year of data for the ASX, NASDAQ, NYSE, LSE, World Indices, and FOREX. So plenty for you to explore.

Comment: Are you using their data to provide a service (albeit free software)? Clause 3 of EODData's [Terms and Conditions](http://www.eoddata.com/about/terms.aspx) states "use the Services only for the User's personal use."

Comment: Hi vegemite4me, thanks for the concern, I have an agreement with EODData.

Answer (score 5):

I'm dissatisfied with the intraday minute data. I've found bad gaps, particularly on Fridays' data. They won't answer complains and they won't fix it either.

Answer (score 5):

I tried them and was very disappointed .No support,no phone number,no answer to several emails.I would strongly suggest using someone else.

Answer (score 4):

Just for some info, maybe useful for someone. I detected spikes in EODData 20yr NASDAQ data (3005 symbols) and found 647 spikes.
Yahoo has many of them detected/removed, so obviously they share the same source of data, at least for something.
And EODData IS NOT doing even simplest automated spike detection. My algorithm is about 20 lines of C# code, very simple. I don't get why they don't do it. Leaving such bad data is much worse than just removing it.
Someone says you get what you pay for, but they say at their site the spikes are detected/corrected, which is obviously not true.

Comment: welcome @Ales, and thank you for the question. Nevertheless it could be great if you could rewrite it around "what is the best way to detect spikes", or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

I used EODData for about a year in order to truly get a feel for the data. I would say for the price it is great, but there are inconsistencies in the data. I had found some serious errors that were never patched. I am sure there were many more but I didn't catch them. If you use them, I would advise running through the data to check for anomalies since they apparently cannot do that. Their coverage of options and global equities is great for the price and it beats scraping Yahoo and Google.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that the EODData website is difficult to understand.  That can be overcome with reasonable support.  I wrote to EODData with a support request one week ago.  I have yet to get *any* response.  This site, absent decent support, is worthless.  I would advise that you avoid it like the plague until the owners start to pay attention to support requests.  As far as I can tell -- with zero response over the course of one week -- the owners don't give a damn about providing any support.

Answer (score 3):

DO NOT USE EOD DATA!!! Their data is incomplete even for 2014... The September zip at 1/5/10/15/30/60 minute bars was generated and only goes up to Sept 28th... Where's the data for the 29th and 30th?

Answer (score 3):

In regards to equity option data, insufficient.  Advertised daily option data, but latest download 3 months old.  Support wont answer or issue refund for my fees.  Sham operation be careful with your membership.  I do recommend.

Answer (score 1):

In replying to is EODDATA data a good site to do business with. Simple, and truthful answer is NO! Data is corrupt and CS is a joke. They, never respond for help. But they are happy to overcharge your CC. They piggy back data from other sites. 6/11/18

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT USE THEM.**

I bought a platinum membership, but I was not happy with the data they provide.

There is no option to cancel the subscription - you have to write an email to them if you want to cancel it.

During the last 2 weeks, I wrote 2 emails and 2 tickets through their page. They responded to none of them.
Today I wrote through all communication ways again, hopefully, they will just cancel it with delay, and I won't have to take any further steps.

Answer (score 0):

No complaints so far with 10 years of eod CME data. This vendor is a godsend. At these prices I don't mind scrubbing. Godspeed.

Answer (score -1):

Try alpha vantage. I have been using them and they have a good api and include dividends and stock splits.

Answer (score -2):

I am and have been a silver member for 3 years with EODDATA. I have had no problems. BTW I write my own code and have a degree in Economics and am a former computer systems analyst. I download their data about once a week. I do not care about hourly price fluctuations or Milan stock exchange or commodities. I am just a simple and profitable investor in the style of Benjamin Graham. EODDATA works. Its simple and has value.